# How to use MoveWindow() in win32 without messing up how the DialogBox looks?

Tags: c, winapi

[image]

[image]

The first photo is BEFORE using the MoveWindow Function.
After using MoveWindow, it ends up like the second photo. Could someone please tell me why this happens, and is there a way to just move the dialog box and not change it's dimensions when using MoveWindow?

Comment: `MoveWindow` won't resize the window unless you tell it to. Give it the existing size for the width/height arguments and all it will do is move it. Or use `SetWindowPos` with the `SWP_NOSIZE` flag.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan, MoveWindow won't resize the window unless you tell it to. Could you please provide ome small reproducible sample?

Comment: Jonathan's solution works perfectly! I am able to achieve the desired result with his suggestion. Thanks for reading through my post you guys :)